# Graphing continuous data points using date and time in R

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, timestamp

I am very new to RStudio so my coding is rudimentary.

I have a data set that contains six (6) columns: date5m, time5m, T5m, date28m, time28m, T28m.  The data set is temperature data at two depths (5m and 28m) with an associate date and time stamp.  My resulting graph appears to place all the data by day rather than a continuous display by the time that it was collected.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)
Aberdeen <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE)
head(Aberdeen)
Aberdeen$ï..date5m = as.Date(Aberdeen$ï..date5m, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
Aberdeen$date28m = as.Date(Aberdeen$date28m, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
ggplot() + geom_point(data = Aberdeen, aes(x = ï..date5m, y = T5m), 
    colour = "darkgreen", size=0.25, na.rm=TRUE) + 
    geom_point(data = Aberdeen, aes(x = date28m, y = T28m), colour = "forestgreen", size=0.25, na.rm=TRUE) + 
    labs(x = "Date", y = "Temperature (\u00B0C)") + 
    ggtitle("Aberdeen") + 
    theme_bw() + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
     scale_x_date(date_breaks = "month", labels=date_format("%b-%Y"))
```

[image: Non-continuous graph]

I would like for the graph to display the data in a continuous fashion using both date and time stamp like this:

[image: Required end results]

Here is the first 10 lines of my data set:

```
structure(list(date5m = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "2018-06-01", class = "factor"), time5m = 
structure(1:10, .Label = c("14:40:30", 
"14:42:34", "14:44:39", "14:46:40", "14:48:43", "14:50:46", "14:52:51", 
"14:54:56", "14:56:59", "14:59:03"), class = "factor"), T5m = c(9.1, 
9.02, 9, 9.12, 9.12, 9.1, 9.06, 9.02, 8.98, 9.02), date28m = 
structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "2018-06-01", class = 
"factor"), 
time28m = structure(1:10, .Label = c("14:39:00", "14:49:00", 
"14:59:00", "15:10:00", "15:20:00", "15:30:00", "15:40:00", 
"15:50:00", "16:00:00", "16:11:00"), class = "factor"), T28m = c(1.93, 
1.93, 1.93, 1.93, 1.93, 1.93, 1.93, 1.93, 1.93, 1.91)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please share a little bit of reproducible data. If you give us the results of `dput(droplevels(Aberdeen[1:10, ]))` it will give us a copy/pasteable version of the first 10 rows of data.

Comment: May I give you a tip, it doesn't have directly to do with your question. I see you have read a csv and are using variables called ï..date1. Those are files saved with a BOM header, maybe by SQL Server or some other software. You can deal with that by including in read.csv() call the argument fileEnconding = "UFT-8-BOM".

Comment: It seems like you could use geom_line() instead of geom_point() to give it the continuous look. We're also looking forwards to the dput() so we can give further advice.

Comment: You need to convert your wide data frame into a long format with either the `gather` or `pivot_longer` function.  See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45795429/how-to-plot-multiple-graphs-on-one-plot-using-a-different-columns-in-a-dataframe

Comment: Added a sample data set @GregorThomas

Comment: I will try adding the argument @user2332849; I was doing a lazy work around to that issue as I could not figure out how to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to tricker than expected since the date and time columns are not consistent across the rows.
I had to manipulate the column names to provide a consistent separator in the name.  I also combined the date and time columns into a single datetime object in order to plot properly.
Once the original data frame was converted from the original wide format into a long format the `ggplot` call was simplified.

"Aberdeen" is the name of the original dataframe from the `read.csv` statement (assume to match the sample data posted). Please see the code comments for additional details:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

#Rename the columns to add a '_' seperator between the letter and first number
#this is needed to make the separation and the pivot easier.
# See the tidyr pivot Vignette "Multiple observations per row"
names(Aberdeen) <- names(Aberdeen) %>% str_replace( "(\\D)(\\d)", "\\1_\\2")

#Adding a rownumber for tracking purposes
#Unite the date and time columns into 1 column
#reshape to long
dflong<-Aberdeen %>% mutate(rowid=row_number()) %>%
  unite("datetime_5m",  c(date_5m,  time_5m)) %>% 
  unite("datetime_28m",  c(date_28m,  time_28m)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols= -rowid, names_to = c(".value", "depth"), names_sep="_") 

#convert datetime column from character to datetime oject:
dflong$datetime<-as.POSIXct(dflong$datetime, "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S", tz="")

#plot grouping and coloring by the depth
ggplot(data = dflong, aes(x = datetime, y = T, group=depth, color=depth)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Temperature (\u00B0C)") + 
  ggtitle("Aberdeen") + 
  theme_bw() + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "hour", labels=date_format("%b-%Y"))
```

[image]